# defining a list of exception classes - Type mismatch error

Tags: java, list, exception, generics, type-conversion

i am trying to define a list of exception classes like so:

```
private static final List<Class<? extends Exception>> SOME_ERRORS = Arrays.asList(NumberFormatException.class, NullPointerException.class);
```

the error i get from Eclipse is this:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Class<? extends RuntimeException>> to List<Class<? extends Exception>>
```

Could you please advise? I don't see why it can't convert a list of Exceptions to a list of Exceptions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for [Reimeus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331079/751158).  However, if you'd prefer to keep the list declared using the parent `Exception` type, this is the best I can come up with (using Java 7 syntax):

```
private static final List<Class<? extends Exception>> SOME_ERRORS = new ArrayList<>();
static{
    SOME_ERRORS.add(NumberFormatException.class);
    SOME_ERRORS.add(NullPointerException.class);
}
```

Your issue is due to `Arrays.asList` automatically determining the proper list type for you.  To compare, this also works without error:

```
private static final List<Class<? extends Exception>> SOME_ERRORS = Arrays.asList(NumberFormatException.class, NullPointerException.class, Exception.class);
```

Especially dealing with "constants" (`static final`s), you're usually best advised to ensure that such arrays / collections can't be modified.  At worst, this can save running into some difficult issues.  For example:

```
private static final List<Class<? extends Exception>> SOME_ERRORS;
static{
    List<Class< ? extends Exception>> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    errors.add(NumberFormatException.class);
    errors.add(NullPointerException.class);

    SOME_ERRORS = Collections.unmodifiableList(errors);
}
```

Comment: that's what surprised me. as soon as i added a FileNotFoundException.class code compiled. I still find it strange, but i think i now see why it's the way it is. thanks

Comment: accepting your answer for this piece of info "Your issue is due to Arrays.asList automatically determining the proper list type for you."

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
List<Class<? extends RuntimeException>> SOME_ERRORS = Arrays.asList(NumberFormatException.class, NullPointerException.class);
```

The generics type returned from `Arrays.asList` will always use the most specific type, i.e. `RuntimeException`. If you added a checked exception to the list, this statement would become:

```
List<Class<? extends Exception>> SOME_ERRORS = Arrays.asList(IOException.class, NumberFormatException.class, NullPointerException.class);
```

Comment: but, don't runtime exceptions extend exceptions? and i clearly want a list of any classes of any exceptions extending the Exception class. What if I add a non-runtime exception to the list?

Comment: to answer my own question, adding a non-runtime exception to the list works fine as is, suddenly compiles.